# Mirroring a game object to create symmetry

Tags: c#, unity, scale

I have a GameObject with a primitive shape that I call "body". I want to create and add a child to it with another primitive shape. I call it 'mutation'. But i want to duplicate the 'mutation' and mirror the duplicate. So they become symmetrical to the 'body'. This way it could resemble wings or legs or eyes.

I've tried to create two children to the mutation called "LeftSide" and "RightSide". I duplicated the new primitive and put one copy in each. I set the Left Side's scale to -1 for the X, Y and Z hoping that it would mirror and create a symmetry with the right side. But its not working out.

So I'm hoping for some tips on ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirroring an object happens only across one plane;  it's not a global -1 scale, as you've done here.

You only want to set the scale to -1 for **one** of the X, Y, or Z axes (Which one depends on which direction you want it to be mirrored).  Leave the other two axes with a scale of 1.